# the method JsonConvert.DeserializeObject converts id's into zero

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I've got a string:

```
string model = "{\"Game\":{\"GameId\":1,\"Board\":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],\"User1Id\":1,\"User2Id\":2,\"UserIdTurn\":1,\"WinnerId\":0,\"IsGameOver\":false},\"User\":{\"UserId\":1,\"UserName\":\"a\",\"Password\":\"a\",\"Password2\":\"a\",\"Games\":[]}}"
```

And when I use this code:

```
GameModel myModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GameModel>(model);
```

It works pretty good but with only one problem - it changes my Game and User id's into zero. why does it happen and how can I solve it?
I write in c# by the way.

those are my classes :

```
        public class GameModel
    {

        public Game Game { get; set; }

        public User User { get; set; }

    }

public class Game
    {

        public Game()
        {
            Board = new SquareState[9];                     
        }

        public Game(int user1Id)
        {
            Board = new SquareState[9];
            User1Id = user1Id;
            UserIdTurn = user1Id;
        }
        public int GameId { get; private set; }

        public SquareState[] Board { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int User1Id { get; set; }

        public int User2Id { get; set; }

        public int UserIdTurn { get; set; }


        public int WinnerId { get; set; }

        public bool IsGameOver { get; set; }

    }

    public class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            Games = new List<Game>();
        }
        public int UserId { get; private set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User Name:")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "re-enter Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords not match")]
        public string Password2 { get; set; }

        public List<Game> Games { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please post also the `GameModel` class definition? Thanks

Comment: The json is not valid. check it on http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I just posted  my classes and I'm going over my json but so far don't know what needs to be changed.

Comment: @Dev-One the json is valid.  It is escaped to make it a valid C# string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your class is deserializing without the `GameId` and `UserId` is because your setter methods for both of these are set to `private` scope.

The deserializer isn't able to access them because they are not available to it.

Try making them public and run it again and they will deserialize as expected:

```
public class Game
{
    ...
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and

```
public class User
{
    ...
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```